# readfile() callback called twice

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am new to nodejs and callbacks.

So I have this code where I read a file when a request to server is initiated via HTTP:

```
var http = require("http");
var fs = require("fs");

http.createServer(function(request,response){

    response.writeHead(200,{'Content-Type':'text/plain'});
    response.end("Server runnning...");

    fs.readFile('new.txt',function(err,data){
        if(err){
            console.error(err);
            return;
        }
        console.log(data.toString());
    });

}).listen(1234);
```

When I run the code, the contents of the file are displayed/logged twice on console.

```
lorem ipsum
lorem ipsum
```

The file contents are:

```
lorem ipsum
```

Comment: Could you edit the question and add the contents of `new.txt` to the question? I'm 99.95% sure it's just `lorem ipsum`, but it helps in helping you to know all the inputs for sure :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you type a URL into the browser's address bar it will typically make two requests:

- One for the page you want to see
- One for `/favicon.ico`

Two requests means two calls to `fs.readFile` since you call that for every request.

Comment: It might call `OPTIONS` request as well. +1 to this answer