# Node.js readdir callback called twice

Tags: javascript, node.js, fs

There have been at least two posts here about this in the past:

[NodeJS readdir() function always being run twice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35714813/nodejs-readdir-function-always-being-run-twice)

[readfile() callback called twice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35563941/readfile-callback-called-twice)

Both have answers to the effect that readdir was itself called twice, so no mystery. But my case is different, as illustrated by this code:

```
console.log('calling readdir');
fs.readdir(folder,
    function (err, files) {
        console.log('readdir callback');
        // ... deal with the files
    }
);
```

which results in this output:

```
calling readdir
readdir callback
readdir callback
```

This does not happen with all folders. As a workaround, I set a flag:

```
let wasCalled;
...
wasCalled = false;
console.log('calling readdir');
fs.readdir(folder,
    function (err, files) {
        if (!wasCalled) {
            console.log('readdir callback');
            wasCalled = true;
            // ... deal with the files
        }
    }
);
```

which avoids processing in the second call:

```
calling readdir
readdir callback
```

I can't see what I'm doing wrong, since the logging indicates that in the first case there are two callbacks for a single call to readdir. But perhaps someone else has encountered this and figured out something other than a bug in readdir?

This is in a renderer process in Electron 1.3.3 with Node.js 6.3.0.

Comment: I can't recreate, which version are you using?

Comment: Can you show us the content of the variable 'folder' when readdir is being called ?

Comment: Just added that to my post. I doubt you'll be able to recreate it, as I only noticed it after using my app on lots of different folders. So far, only one folder does this. Perhaps my files system (Windows 10) is screwed up, but, even if it is, there should be only one callback. I've checked, and the err argument is null both times. Forgot to mention that the files array is the same with both callbacks, and contains all files (only 3 of them).

Comment: OK, I added to the console.log line and got this:

    calling readdir with  P:\Panos

Comment: I've just tried it with a some different folder structures, I always get exactly one callback - no matter how many subdirs/files.

Comment: Yes, me, too. As I said, only one folder (so far) causes this misbehavior.

Comment: Any idea if one is called with an error and the other one isn't?

Comment: I mentioned that above. err is null both times, and files array is whole directory, which consists of 3 files. (If it had, say, 10,000 files, I could understand some undocumented paging going on.) However, even if err were set the second time, the docs say that there is only one callback.

Comment: [deleted comment]